# añadir una pregunta de confirmacion

Tags: php

Quisiera añadir una pregunta de confirmacion para borrar un elemento de una tabla con `class= confirm`

como lo incluiria aqui?

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id_seller=" . $row->id . "'>delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Con javascript del lado del cliente.

Comment: Lo sencillo es `href='if(confirm("¿lo borro?")) { document.location="delete.php?id_seller=' . $row->id . '" }'`

Comment: Estaba probando con esto pero no me funciona: echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id_seller=" . $row->id_seller .  "' onclick="return confirm(\'Really delete?\');">Delete</a></td>";

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de como se hace: <a href="delete.php?id=22" onclick = "if (! confirm('Quieres eliminar esto?')) { return false; }">Eliminar</a>

Answer (score 0):

A continuación te propongo la siguiente solución.
Suponiendo que imprimes en cada td la clase .confirm y agregar el atributo id, podrías usar el siguiente código.

```js
$('.confirm').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  href = $(this).attr('href');
  // agregar alerta o modal 
   if(confirm("¿Quieres borrar este elemento?")){
      window.location.href = href;
   }
});
```

```html
<td><a class="confim" id="<?php echo $id_seller ?>" href='delete.php?id_seller=" . $row->id . "'>delete</a></td>
```